# How to manage reservations with Drupal for something that is not something like a room?

Tags: 7, bookings

I am looking for a reservation module for either Drupal 6 or 7. I know there is a really good looking module for room reservations for Drupal 7 but my use case is different. I am looking for a reservation/booking module that could be used for booking photographers or DJs. I have searched around but haven't really found anything suitable yet.

The [Room Reservations](https://www.drupal.org/project/room_reservations) module that is being created for Drupal 7 looks great, but it needs to be generalized so that the administrator could define what it is that needs to be booked. Right now it is hard coded for rooms only.

Does anyone know of such a module and more importantly worked with it?

Answer (score 4):

**For Drupal 6** there is a stable release of [Simple Reservation](http://drupal.org/project/simple_reservation/) module.

> This module provides a simple and easy way to reserve items which can be created by the administrator. Examples for it's usage can be hotel rooms, boats, cars, airplanes, basically anything you can think of which can be reserved by one individual.

**For Drupal 7** you can try [Reservations API](http://drupal.org/project/reservations).

> The core focus in on the Reservations API that enables any Content Type to be reservable based on a variety of default settings. A **Reservation -> Confirmation -> Checkout -> Checkin** workflows is included, but it is created entirely using Views. Additional modules can enforce custom validation, add pricing, or add additional availability to the basic hours of operation.

Comment: I will look into both suggestions. I take it that both can be integrated with Ubercart?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following module: [Booking Time Slots](http://drupal.org/project/booking_timeslots).

This module works as extension to Calendar and provides nice UI (customisable) for slot booking (reservation).

This is the screenshot of the UI exposed from the module.

#### Drupal 6.x

[image: Drupal 6.x - Booking Time Slots]

You can customize how many slots are period (hour, half-hour or custom). You can easily override template files based on your needs. Once the user make the reservation of specified slot, it's booked.

#### Drupal 7.x

[image: Drupal 7.x - Booking Time Slots]

For other modules, check: [Comparison of Booking System modules](https://groups.drupal.org/node/137544)

Comment: This looks interesting for my use case. Thanks for posting about this particular module.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a summmary of the modules and/or distributions you may want to look at for managing reservations, for something that is not a room (or a variation of that). These modules have a stable release, and can be used  for either D6 or D7 (quotes are from their project pages):

- [Availability Calendars](https://www.drupal.org/project/availability_calendars) (D6 or D7).

  > ... allows you to add an availability calendar to entities. Example use cases are tourist accommodation, e.g. bed and breakfast, holiday homes or self catered apartments, and car or motor bike rental.
  >
  > An availability calendar shows your customers at what dates your accommodation is still available and at what dates it is already booked.
- [Simple Reservation](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_reservation/) (D6 or D7).

  > ... provides a simple and easy way to reserve items which can be created by the administrator. Examples for it's usage can be hotel rooms, boats, cars, airplanes, basically anything you can think of which can be reserved by one individual.
  >
  > The module provides the possibility to create reservations for other users (dependend on the permissions), and provides also restrictions in the maximum number of reservations a user can make and a maximum time a reservation can be made in advance.
  >
  > There is NO support for payment, booking and what ever one could imagine beyond the pure and simple reservation, and it is also NOT intended to create more than this simple functionality.
- [MERCI](https://www.drupal.org/project/merci) (D6 or D7).

  > ... can extend any content type into a list of unique reservable items (like studios) or buckets of interchangeable items (like DV cameras). We followed the approach used by Organic Groups, Feed API, and Scheduler and added MERCI's configuration to the Edit tab of those content types.
- [Resource Conflict](https://www.drupal.org/project/resource_conflict) (D6 or D7).

  > ... allows for users to book resources for use during events. For example, a student can book a microscope for use within their lab.

## Booking Systems Comparison

Refer to [Comparison of Booking System modules](https://groups.drupal.org/node/137544) for a comparison of various modules related to bookings / reservations.

This comparison contains some other modules (not mentioned in my answer here) that might be worth considering also, e.g. in case of requirements that are slightly different (as compared to those in the question here).

## How to pick the module that fits best

I've ordered my recommended shortlist above by number of reported installs. Though that is often a good first indicator, it should not be used as the only criterium to pick a module.

So do your homework to pick the right one for you. E.g. by using criteria such as those I often use for selecting module, as mentioned in the community documentation about [Maintenance Scorecards](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985#scorecards).

Here is the intro about it (from that page):

> ... contains a list of 23 criteria (=28-5) that might help to evaluate
>   the maintenance and support of contributed modules. Below is an
>   attempt to apply those criteria to each of the native charting modules
>   ...

Obvious, these scorecards are related to "charting modules", but the same criteria are applicable, IMHO, wheneven you need to decide between multiple modules.

Also note that I've ordered my shortlist above by number of reported installs. Though that is often a good first indicator, it should not be used as the only criterium to pick a module. So do your homework to pick the right one for you.

**Disclosure**: I'm the author of that community documentation page (partially inspired by the 28 criteria in the issue linked near the beginning of the scorecards paragraph),
I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).