# Can I make a node reservable?

Tags: nodes

Is it possible to make a node reservable (for users that do not have rights to edit/add content, or even anonymous users)? The node in this case is a "timeslot" for a service.

So there would be lots of nodes and each node could only be reserved once. At reservation time the person making the reservation should give his/her contact details. No payment or anything like that is made at this point.

I found the tutorial about [Using webfom 3.x to reserve items/nodes in Drupal 7](http://www.ishwor.info/using-webfom-3x-reserve-itemsnodes-drupal-7) (using the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module to "reserve a node"), but not sure if it is the best way (I am looking into it).

Or if anyone can just point me into the right direction, would be appreciated.

Comment: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced, was solved by a cache clear, or was a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers." – kiamlaluno... hmm I don't understand how this question falls into this category. I will improve my question if it is not clear.

Comment: Have a look at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37078/how-to-manage-reservations-with-drupal-for-something-that-is-not-something-like/174020#174020

Comment: Another approach could be to use the "Flag" module, whereas "flagging a node" in your case would be equivalent to "reserve this node for me". To ensure a node could only be flagged once, you'd have to add some logic to it using the "Rules" module. The beauty of this approach, I think, is that it could work without such user having EDIT access to the node, and you could even make it work for anonymous users. Assumption: all relevant "data" of such node reservation (maybe timeslots?) have to be included as fields in the node being reserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the [reservation API](https://www.drupal.org/project/reservations)

Comment: The OP is talking of users without edit permissions, so I guess he doesn't mean a module for reserving rooms.

Comment: hehe  - i see, and taught there we're two questions - but it was more like a typo in the question ..

Comment: I  edited the question, since the question was put on hold as off-topic. If I cant find a way to do this seperatly, I will look into using a reservation module and maybe ask a question about that seperately.

Comment: And I will look into reservation API (ofcourse I woill have to learn how to use it first). I had heard about it, but some how overlooked using it in this case.

Comment: depending on your needs they may be other modules, like https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_reservation

Comment: I went with the option I had in my own question and started braking down questions into smaller ones because this one kept being putt on hold. Your answer was the best one to my original question. Thank you for your input.