# How to make booking calendar for accommodation facility

Tags: 7, datetime, bookings

I have web, let's call it `AccomovationInSkyResort.com`. It has 2 facilities with 3 entities which can be booked out (reserved):

1. Appartment house:

   a) 1th floor **(1)**

   b) 2nd floor **(2)**
2. Cottage **(3)**

How to make "booking (reservation) calendar" for accommodation facility?

By "*booking calendar*" I mean calendar showing available (not booked out) nights. I need 3 calendars at all.

I did some experiments with [calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar) module but it isn't so nice solution.

How did you solved this problem?

Comment: I have decided to use [Availability Calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/availability_calendars).

Comment: @jasom.dotnet But availability calendar does not have booking and payment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the module you mentioned is good for it. Each of the entity can have a boolean field "Booked". So it could have values 0 or 1. You can filter out nodes according this field value in you calendar view.

I suppose, " Apartment house 2nd floor" is just one entity, not a type of entity.

Comment: Also [rooms](https://www.drupal.org/project/rooms) looks good. Various [booking modules](https://groups.drupal.org/node/137544) and [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/37078/13287) is similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a summmary of the modules you may want to look at for managing reservations. These modules have a stable release, and can be used  for either D6 or D7 (quotes are from their project pages):

- [Availability Calendars](https://www.drupal.org/project/availability_calendars).

  > ... allows you to add an availability calendar to entities. Example use cases are tourist accommodation, e.g. bed and breakfast, holiday homes or self catered apartments, and car or motor bike rental.
  >
  > An availability calendar shows your customers at what dates your accommodation is still available and at what dates it is already booked.
- [Simple Reservation](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_reservation/).

  > ... provides a simple and easy way to reserve items which can be created by the administrator. Examples for it's usage can be hotel rooms, boats, cars, airplanes, basically anything you can think of which can be reserved by one individual.
  >
  > The module provides the possibility to create reservations for other users (dependend on the permissions), and provides also restrictions in the maximum number of reservations a user can make and a maximum time a reservation can be made in advance.
  >
  > There is NO support for payment, booking and what ever one could imagine beyond the pure and simple reservation, and it is also NOT intended to create more than this simple functionality.
- [MERCI](https://www.drupal.org/project/merci).

  > ... can extend any content type into a list of unique reservable items (like studios) or buckets of interchangeable items (like DV cameras). We followed the approach used by Organic Groups, Feed API, and Scheduler and added MERCI's configuration to the Edit tab of those content types.
- [Resource Conflict](https://www.drupal.org/project/resource_conflict).

  > ... allows for users to book resources for use during events. For example, a student can book a microscope for use within their lab.

I've ordered my recommended shortlist above by number of reported installs. Though that is often a good first indicator, it should not be used as the only criterium to pick a module.

Comment: availability calendar sounds good but does not allow booking. Would be great if it can. Does it? Would you suggest Entity Registration module?